# Looking for examples of simplex tableaus

Tags: linear-programming

(a) Such that the LPP is unbounded and thus has no optimal solutions.

(b) Such that the tableau represents an optimal solution to the LPP.

Just looking to get some examples of these, to familiarize and figure out how to come up with them in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**HINTS**
here are the problems, can you come up with the corresponding tableaus?

(a) how about $\max x$ subject to $x \ge 0$?

(b) $\max x$ subject to $x \le 0$ at the solution point $x = 0$.

Comment: Need a bit more guidance. New to simplex and related material